# Can't delete LV (volume is used by another device)

Tags: centos, lvm

We had a KVM machine running on a CentOS 6.7 server and have since deleted the VM. However, the logical volume that was assigned to the VM has remained on the system and I can't find a way to delete it.

I have tried all the obvious commands with no luck, such as:

```
[root@server ~]# lvremove /dev/vg/test
  Logical volume vg/test is used by another device.

[root@server ~]# lvchange -an -f /dev/vg/test
  Logical volume vg/test is used by another device.

[root@server ~]# lvscan | grep /dev/vg/test
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg/test' [10.00 GiB] inherit

[root@server ~]# dmsetup remove vg-test
device-mapper: remove ioctl on vg-test failed: Device or resource busy
```

Extra commands output:

```
[root@server ~]# mount -l
/dev/md2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
/dev/md1 on /tmp type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg-backup on /backups type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)

[root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2               96G   20G   72G  22% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              591M  184M  377M  33% /boot
/dev/md1              283M  2.1M  266M   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg-backup
                      197G   19G  169G  10% /backups
```

How can I delete this logical volume?

Comment: If I am not wrong, md0 , md1 , md2 are raid volumes. So is there any chance that */dev/vg/test* is a part of any raid volumes. Also add the output of command `cat /proc/mdstat`.

Comment: Any chance a namespace mount was created by a process? Check if the device is anywhere is `lsof` output.

Comment: Other option is there is a loopback device - check output of `losetup -a`. May be a duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/umount-device-is-busy-why

Comment: @GauravPundir post your comment as answer. You deserve the upvotes and marked as solution :)

Answer (score 3):

In this case ,it seems that the device-mapper is  creating a mapping which counted as ‘in-use’. Check for the mapping via:

## dmsetup info -c | grep test

It should give some output like [*in mycase logical volume is data_vol-data_logVol00* ]:

**dmsetup info -c | grep data**

*data_vol-data_logVol00   253   0 L--w    1    5      0 LVM-9BAtA4lpzSlsMEg8Wrpw71qdfegiR4zxdmzG0MggVseJatR12wjqtGY8qYZatIybB*

Then use that to find out what is holding it:

**ls -la /sys/dev/block/253:0/holders/**

*total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jun  5 17:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 0 May 18 20:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 24 18:25 dm-1 -> ../../dm-1*

Then do a dmsetup remove on that device-mapper device:

## dmsetup remove /dev/dm-1

And you’re good to go with lvremove:

## lvremove -v  /dev/vg/test

Answer (score 1):

We found that there was RAID installed on the problematic LV's - we got the real devices by running `ls -l /dev/mapper` and then `cat /proc/mdstat`.

It was then necessary to deactive the RAID arrays with the following command:

```
mdadm -S /dev/mdXXX
```

After that the LV's could be successfully deleted using the `lvremove` command as posted in the original question.

Comment: If this is solved, please mark it as solved by clicking the check mark next to the answer so that it turns green.